# spark variable in pyspark vs SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When we start pyspark (spark 2.4), it comes with a spark variable call underline functionality.
so when to call and use SparkSession and SparkContext methods if "spark" is already available.

Answer (score 1):

Using spark 2.4, you probably see something like this in your log:

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application...).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
```

According to [databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html):

> In previous versions of Spark, you had to create a SparkConf and SparkContext to interact with Spark, as shown here:

```
//set up the spark configuration and create contexts
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSessionZipsExample").setMaster("local")
// your handle to SparkContext to access other context like SQLContext
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf).set("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

> Whereas in Spark 2.0 the same effects can be achieved through
>   SparkSession, without expliciting creating SparkConf, SparkContext or
>   SQLContext, as they’re encapsulated within the SparkSession.

So:

1. In your case spark is just an alias for the SparkSession.
2. You not need to use SparkContext as it is encapsulated within the SparkSession.